# My app is crashing with a SecurityException saying it needs file IO. How do I find out which file is being accessed so I can grant it permission?

Tags: c#, .net, sandbox, appdomain

I don't want to give it unrestricted access to the filesystem... How can I get the name of the file that its' demanding `FileIOPermission` for? I poked around in the exception helper and didn't see anything...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Sysinternal's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) tool for this, filtering by your process name and operation (read file).

"Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity."

Comment: Hmm, how do I make DiskMon display filenames? All I see is sector numbers, which isn't all that useful... And where is the filter option?

Comment: @ekolis Sorry, I answered by heart, I have updated my answer

Comment: Hmm, if I  run my app with My Computer permissions, I get a bunch of extraneous files that it already has access to, but if I run it with Internet permissions, then I don't see where it failed; I guess the request to access the file never made it through to ProcMon? Or is it listed under an IronPython process rather than my app's main process? The code that's crashing is Python code.

Comment: @ekolis It will be listed under IronPython exe.

Comment: even if I run IronPython as a DLL?